# Decode base64 string without newline character

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64

I am working with some base64 data. The expected output is 6 hex numbers like in the first example. However sometimes I get a newline character like in the second example (with 5 hex values)

```
base64.b64decode('DAAI9BTT')
b'\x0c\x00\x08\xf4\x14\xd3'
```

```
base64.b64decode('DAAKRRTT')
b'\x0c\x00\nE\x14\xd3'
```

I suspect I get the value 0A and this is converted to newline. When I trim the newline I miss a hex value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\n` just comes from the string representation of the bytearray from `__repr__`. Extract the contents of the byte array into a list, and you get what you expect:

```
[p for p in base64.b64decode('DAAKRRTT')]
# Output: [12, 0, 10, 69, 20, 211]
```

Or, in hex:

```
[hex(p) for p in base64.b64decode('DAAKRRTT')]
# Output: ['0xc', '0x0', '0xa', '0x45', '0x14', '0xd3']
```